# how to transition left to right push with code

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I want to go to next page from first page and use this code :

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:setting animated:YES];
```

and this code go to next page right to left and I want to do this left to right .
how to do it???

please guide me.

Comment: @Dima my friend where I add that answer code???